# how can i search in p-blast against UNIPROT(not only swissprot)

Tags: blast, uniprot

i need to search for one protein against UNIPROT in BLAST for a selected organism.
How can I do it? (SWSISSPROT+TREMBL)
THANKS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any online tool enabling a search against TrEMBL. You probably will have to set up your own local BLAST environment, roughly following these steps:

1. [download blast+](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=Download) - but there might be an easier way to install the software, depending on your operating system (e.g. on Ubuntu you can just `sudo apt install ncbi-blast+`)
2. [download target databases](https://www.uniprot.org/downloads)
3. [build local database](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279688/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you a lot for your answer!unfortunately my programming skills are not so strong!

Answer (score 0):

UniProt provides a BLAST service (https://www.uniprot.org/blast) which you can run against several UniProt databases, or you could use the Expasy BLAST too, at https://web.expasy.org/blast.